# How to negotiate conditions for going to the office in work-from-home situation?

Tags: travel, reimbursement, work-from-home

I work from home, which is about 2-2.5 hours away by train costing about 20-25€ euros for one direction.

For regular work, I never have to visit the office.

For meetings with clients I may sometimes have to.

Now my boss (also the owner) said that for 2-3 trips to the office per year he does not find necessary for the company to compensate me. Everything beyond that he has left unclear.

I feel just agreeing would leave me in a bad spot.

My concerns are that (1) for these three visits there is a very high incentive for me and only for me to try to avoid meetings with customers and that (2) what happens beyond these three times is unclear and would again require me bringing it up and negotiating.

1) What are reasonable models for compensating this kind of travel I could bring up?

2) How do I best frame that I want to at least split the money and time disincentives between me and the company?

Comment: If this is in Germany, this is most likely a tax thing - we have the same situation where i work. All trips are paid, only the ones to your official working location are not. AFAIU the logic is that it is your responsibility to go to your workplace and that your employer can not deduce this as costs.

Answer (score 4):

I would respond by establishing a threshold for what **does**, in his mind, constitute enough travel to justify compensation.

75 Euros per year is a very petty amount to get irritated over.  Any arguments you get into over this will make you come across as unreasonable, cheap, and petty.

Your costs at a maximum come down to 6.5 Euros a month.  Let it go.

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on your contract/local laws.

There is a very good chance it does not matter what you say because it will dictated by your contract and if not perhaps a law.

I know where I work, if you work from home, the employer is under no obligation to pay for the employee to attend meetings.